# Failed to get td value by attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function() {

  // get the current row
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st table cell TD value
  var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd table cell TD value
  var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value
  alert(col3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <tr>
      <td data-label="Id">Item ID</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">Amount</td>
      <td data-label="Buyer" id="qwe">Buyer</td>
      <td data-label="Items">Items</td>
      <td data-label="Email">Email</td>
      <td data-label="Actions">
        <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">ADD</i></a>
        <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
        <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and relevant *context* (ie for `this`).  See [mcve].   Is your event using an arrow function `=>`?

Comment: First is `currentRow` returning the `tr`? Second you might wanner try `.text()` and not `.val()`

Comment: As one of the answers mentioned; `<td>` tags don't have a built-in value attribute, nor have you included one.

Comment: You must have well-formed HTML.  I've added your (rollbacked) edit as a snippet - it still doesn't work.  *but* if you add `<table>` and `</table>` around the `<tr>` - then it works perfectly.  Example with/without `<table>` : https://jsfiddle.net/doks245y/    If your original code *does* contain `<table>` then please update the snippet to include your actual code (without php tags) so that it *demonstrates the issue*.

Comment: I have added HTML, Jquery part. How can get td value on click?? – 
@freedomn-m

Comment: Add the missing `<table>` and `</table>`

Comment: <td>s don't have values. Do you want innerText? innerHTML? Where is your current script failing?

Comment: @mykaf OP is now using `.text()` - updated the question after comments/answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to determine without seeing your DOM structure. Or clear question. But to get the text of that `<td>` including it's children, you could use `.text()`

Example:

```
currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score -1):

table `td` does not have any attribute `value`. You can try using `innerText`

`var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").innerText;`

Comment: Thanks for response, but innerText not working for me, it's showing undefined

Comment: `.innerText` *here* will be called on a jquery object as `currentRow` = `$(this).closest("tr");`  - so gives `undefined` - you need either `.find(..).eq(0).innerText` to convert the TD to a DOM node, or the more sensible `.find(..).text()`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have added HTML, Jquery part. How can get td value on click??